# Regular Expression to find all shared libraries that end with /lib/ and not a subdir of that?

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to get all shared libraries from a root location but only want to list the ones in `/lib/*` and not under another sub-directory as in `/lib/some_subdir` (to be clear /lib /usr/lib /usr/local/lib /whatever/lib are all okay if no subdir under it)

For bash I have:

`find / -type f,l -regex '.*/lib/.*\.so\(\.\|$\).*'`

But that catches the subdirs, how can I have it ignore those?

TIA!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.*` in `/lib/.*\.so` maches including subdirs.
Try to replace it to `[^/]*`

Answer (score 0):

Using `find`

```
$ find / -type f,l -regex '/\(\([^/]*/\)+\)?lib/[a-z0-9.]*.so'
```